# SQL Query Left Join Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I was sure to implement yesterday and Have used `LEFT JOIN` if the other table has no value.
My Problem now is What if you are unsure which table has value and which table has value.

I have tried this query.

```
$query ="SELECT record.student_name,record.student_id,record.student_finger,record.student_section,record.activity_type,record.activity_title,record.score,record.teacher_id,record.activity_id,record.subject_id,attendance.status,attendance.date
        FROM tbl_record record
        LEFT JOIN tbl_attendance attendance on record.student_id=attendance.student_number
        WHERE record.subject_id='$subject_id' and record.teacher_id='$teacher_id' and record.student_section='$section';";
```

But Unfortunately, If my record table is empty, It will not show anything.

What Im tryng to achieve is,
If `table_record` is empty and `tbl_attendance` is not, it will show records in `tbl_attendance`,
and if `table_attendance` is empty and `table_record` is not, it will show records in table_record.

Comment: For that you need `FULL OUTER JOIN`. But that doesn't make much sense since there won't be any subject, teacher or section info so when you try and filter on it (in your `where`), you'll get no results. If you want a report by teacher X, but there is nothing in `tbl_record`, what do you expect to come back? It seems like you have a data integrity issue

Comment: Maybe I should just put attendance on tbl_record.

Comment: Tables model 'things' or 'activities'. What does each table represent here? a table called `tbl_record` gives me no clue what that table is meant to represent. `tbl_attendance` does give me a clue. If you have a record in tbl_attendance with a given student_number, how could that student number not be in `tbl_record`? You would have to be somehow inventing `student_id` values out of thin air. What you need to do is understand the requirements in a non technical language, i.e. ask a question. You might find the question makes no sense at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change LEFT JOIN to FULL OUTER JOIN, adapt the WHERE clause and let us know how it goes.

```
SELECT 
    record.student_name,
    coalesce(record.student_id, attendance.student_number),
    record.student_finger,
    record.student_section,
    record.activity_type,
    record.activity_title,
    record.score,
    record.teacher_id,
    record.activity_id,
    record.subject_id,
    attendance.status,
    attendance.date
FROM tbl_record record
FULL OUTER JOIN tbl_attendance attendance on record.student_id=attendance.student_number
WHERE (record.subject_id='$subject_id' and record.teacher_id='$teacher_id' 
       and record.student_section='$section') 
   or record.subject_id is null;
```

This is a draft MySql version, where FULL OUTER JOIN is not supported. You can replace all record.* fields with NULLs in the RIGHT JOIN part:

```
SELECT 
    record.student_name,
    record.student_id,
    record.student_finger,
    record.student_section,
    record.activity_type,
    record.activity_title,
    record.score,
    record.teacher_id,
    record.activity_id,
    record.subject_id,
    attendance.status,
    attendance.date
FROM tbl_record record
LEFT JOIN tbl_attendance as attendance on 
    record.student_id = attendance.student_number
WHERE (record.subject_id='$subject_id' and record.teacher_id='$teacher_id' 
       and record.student_section='$section') 
UNION
SELECT 
    record.student_name,
    attendance.student_number,
    record.student_finger,
    record.student_section,
    record.activity_type,
    record.activity_title,
    record.score,
    record.teacher_id,
    record.activity_id,
    record.subject_id,
    attendance.status,
    attendance.date
FROM tbl_record as record
RIGHT JOIN tbl_attendance as attendance on 
    record.student_id = attendance.student_number
WHERE record.subject_id is null
;
```

Comment: Okay. I will try this and be back to you for result

Comment: Though you still need to think about your model, as Nick.McDermaid pointed out.

Comment: Is `attendance` not a property of a `student`? Can an `attendance` record exist without a `student` reference? Not likely, I think.

Comment: It's still empty, ATM I have no record in tbl_record but I have In tbl_attendance.
Yeah. Maybe I should

Comment: Well, My Employer wants it that way, he's giving me a hard time.

Comment: I created a [simplified demo](http://rextester.com/UIF46444), which works as I was expected, at least as per my understanding of your problem. Can you check this and compare it to your query?

Comment: And consider replacing record.student_id by `coalesce(record.student_id, attendance.student_number)`. Updated my answer (but not the demo).

Comment: I have edited your demo and that's the way I want, but for your given query, im receiving error. I'll just take a look at this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137523/discussion-between-charles-galvez-and-giorgos-altanis).

Comment: Updated the answer to cover MySql (untested, though), but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just Change "Left JOIN" to "FULL OUTER JOIN"

```
           SELECT * 
             FROM tbl_Students S
  FULL OUTER JOIN tbl_Attendance A
               ON S.StudentID = A.AttendanceStudentID
```